# Changing name in a variable according to users inputs in python

Tags: python, variables, input

I have Homework to complete, about a person signing up for a program. And one of the requirements were : 'Generate the client ID, which is made up of the first 2 letters of the client’s first name'. These are my codings so far:

```
firstname = input ("Can you please insert your first name. -")
    print ( "Hello " + firstname )
```

Now how do I generate the ID name, using the first two letters of the users input.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make unique id's you need to use `uuid`

```
import uuid
print firstName[:2] + uuid.uuid4()
```